# Apply CSS formatting to override it only at TD level

Tags: css, overriding, html-table

I am currently working on page that uses a CSS file that cannot be modified so I usually add my own CSS to override some of the settings. I am stuck where I want to modify a CSS tag but only to affect the TD in a table, not anywhere else.

This is the tag in the CSS file that I cannot modify:

```
.medtext { font-size: 10pt; } 
.medtext { color: #000000; }
```

And what I want to do is if this tag is used in a TD to change the color of the background:

```
table.medtext td {background-color:#ffc477!important}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<span class='medtext'>Some Text that should not be affected</span>

<table><tr>
<td class='medtext'>The background color should change here</td>
<td class='medtext'>here too!</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Add space in front of `!important`

Comment: why use `!important`? you should only need to do `td.mdtext { styles here }` excluding the `!important`

Comment: I added important just in case something else was interfering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your correct code should be

```
    span.medtext {color:#eee! important;}
td:nth-child(1).medtext {color:red! important;}
td:nth-child(2).medtext {color:orange! important;}
```

Comment: This worked! thank you! I have a question regarding the space after the important (even though I will not use it since your answer worked). I have been using CSS compressors and it removes any type of spacing and the code has been working without any problems. For example http://csscompressor.com/ removes all the spaces

Comment: Well, The correct format is to use color:#eee !important; however it also works with this color:#eee! important; Cheers!